# Finding extreme values in vector elements in R

Tags: r

I have a vector like this:

```
x<-c(-0.193,-0.126,-0.275,-0.375,-0.307,-0.347,-0.159,-0.268,-0.013,0.070,0.346,
0.376,0.471,0.512,0.291,0.554,0.185,0.209,0.057,0.058,-0.157,-0.291,-0.509,
-0.534,-0.239,-0.389,0.060,0.250,0.279,0.116,0.052,0.201,0.407,0.360,0.065,
-0.167,-0.572,-0.984,-1.044,-1.039,-0.831,-0.584,-0.425,-0.362,-0.154,0.207,
0.550,0.677,0.687,0.856,0.683,0.375,0.298,0.581,0.546,0.098,-0.081)
```

I would like to find the position of the lowest number each time >=5 consecutive values are <-0.5. In the example that is the value **-1.044**.

How do I find this?

What I have done is this:

```
xx<-ifelse(x>.5,1,NA)
xx

aa<-rle(xx)
zz <- rep(FALSE, length(xx))
zz[sequence(aa$lengths) == 1] <- aa$lengths >= 5 & aa$values == 1
zz
```

But then I just find the position of the first value and not the extreme.

Any help?

Comment: Questions like this that just ask for code are likely to be closed.  Please share what you have tried and why it isn't working.  Otherwise it sounds like you want us to do your work for you! (take a look at `rle` while you're at it)

Comment: I have tried using  rle, but I was just able to find the position where the 5 consecutive values start. Not sure whether I can use rle. Need a hint how to find the extreme value.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for posting what you've tried.

I'd just use a logical comparison for `xx`:

```
xx <- x < -0.5
```

Then your rle logic becomes:

```
aa <- rle(xx)
zz <- aa$lengths >= 5 & aa$values
```

From there, identify which values of `zz` are true and use `cumsum` to get the indicies of `x` (this is oversimplified since there is only once instance but you get the picture):

```
first <- which(zz)
idxs <- cumsum(aa$lengths[1:first])
min(x[idxs[first-1]:idxs[first]])
```

In the instance where you have multiple matches, `first` will be a vector with length > 1.  In that case, make a function and you can `apply` it to your vector:

```
myfun <- function(y) {
    idxs <- c(0, cumsum(aa$lengths[1:y]))
    min(x[idxs[y]:idxs[y+1]])
}

set.seed(20)
x <- rnorm(100)
xx <- x < -0.5
aa <- rle(xx)
zz <- aa$lengths >= 3 & aa$values
first <- which(zz)

sapply(first, myfun)
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply @Justin, however your solution give me the value, whereas I was looking for the position of the value. So I am trying to get an output vector with 56x FALSE and 1x TRUE at the position of the extreme value

Comment: I bet that is something you can figure out... see `which.min`.

Answer (score 0):

A function with the apply function inside:

```
find.val <- function(x,threshold,n,all=T){
  tmp <- rle(x < threshold)
  cs <- cumsum(tmp$lengths)
  dfcs <- data.frame(indices=c(0,cs[-length(cs)])+1,l=cs)
  pos <- (apply(dfcs,1,function(y) which.min(x[y[1]:y[2]])+y[1]-1))[tmp$values==1 & tmp$lengths >= n]
  if(all==T) return(pos)
  pos[which.min(x[pos])]
```

}

if you set all=T you get all matches otherwise only the position of the lowest match.
Example:

```
find.val(x,-0.5,5,all=T)
```